# is there a limit to the number of bundle id's that one can specify for native iOS apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I keep trying to add a new bundle ID for my native iOS app, and although the system says that it's saved, when I go back 30 minutes later the ID I added is no longer there.

Currently I have 6 bundle's in the app.

Thanks guys/gals!

Comment: Anyone feel free to tell me I'm wrong but this kind of threw me off... Shouldn't an app only have one?

Comment: How can you have more than one bundle ID in one app? I may be wrong, but AFAIK, you can only have 1.

Comment: You can 100% have more than one. You can also have more than one URL scheme suffix.

Comment: It's for sharing your Facebook app ID across different iOS apps - see  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#sharedappid