# Limitation of iOS bundle ID count and URL scheme suffixes count linked to one Facebook App ID

Tags: ios, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a limit to the number of bundle id's that one can specify for native iOS apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506336/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-bundle-ids-that-one-can-specify-for-native-io)

I am developing an iOS SDK that must be connected to a single Facebook Application ID. Developers using this SDK will each be assigned their own iOS bundle ID and URL Scheme Suffix linked to the Application ID.

Given that there may be a large number of developers utilizing this SDK, is there any theoretical limit on the number of iOS bundle ID's and URL Scheme Suffixes that can be linked to one Facebook Application ID?

Comment: Semi-related question: did your lawyers check if this complies with section 2 of Facebook's platform policies? sharing data between apps like this may not be allowed

Comment: I will confirm with my lawyer today, but as far as my non-legal mind can tell, we are well within the scope of the policies. There is no "between-app" sharing because the SDK merely adds functionality to apps it is implemented in, all authentication and gathering of log-in credentials is handled within the SDK, and not available to the developers using it to manipulate.

Comment: Fair enough, i'll leave that to you then - as far as the specific question is concerned I'm afraid i don't know - it's probably safer to use one Facebook App ID per third-party iOS App, and have the shared/common functionality provided via communications via your own server/api